# If $(t-2)= e^{3(x-1)}$ then $x=?$

Tags: exponential-function

If $(t-2)= e^{3(x-1)} $ then $x=?$. I guess I have to change the right side of the equation to get the x to the other side.

Comment: Take $\ln$ on both sides, divide both sides by $3$, add $1$ to both sides.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Taking the natural logarithm of both sides we obtain
$$\text{ln}(t-2)=\text{ln}(e^{3(x-1)})$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \text{ln}(t-2)={3(x-1)}\text{ln}(e)$$

Note that $\text{ln}(e)=1$. So we obtain

$$\Leftrightarrow \text{ln}(t-2)={3(x-1)}$$

Then you just solve for $x$ by  dividing both sides by 3, adding 1 to both sides as @peterwhy suggested.